# Append more data to serialized json blobs

Tags: json, serialization, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to query employee data from a rest endpoint periodically and save it to my SQL Server DB using an ADF copy activity. All employee data that is queried on the day is added to an azure blob with the filename corresponding to that day. In my Azure function, I serialize my object using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee)` and store it as **fileName_currentDate.txt** after which the data looks something like this:

```
[
 {
  name: "abc",
  address: "pqr"
 },
 {
  name:"efg",
  address: "efg"
 }
]
```

**Problem**: I want to keep appending more employees to the file with the matching date part.

**Constraint**: I don't want to download the existing blob to the server using something like `blob.DownloadToStream(stream)`, de-serialize it ,add the extra data to my object, and then save it back to the blob container. This will be an expensive operation when the number of times I need to append is large and also when the blob size doesn't fit into memory.

What are my options here?

I see that there's support for **Append Blob Storage** which is what I plan to use in my app, however I cannot understand how I'd add more data to my json blob.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/incrementally-copy-new-files-by-lastmodifieddate-with-azure-data-factory/) indicates that you could configure LastModifiedDate property in the copy activity to build a pipeline with the capability of incrementally copying new and changed file.

However,it is really inappropriate to constantly add data to a single file, which can lead to very slow loading and difficult viewing of data. Based on your business requirements,i would suggest you to increment data in a unit time(e.g. every day) and store the new data into separate files named by the timestamp.

If you do so, maybe [azure stream analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/) is the more suitable choice for you i think.

ASA supports [Azure Blob Storage input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#stream-data-from-blob-storage) and [Azure SQL DB as output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-sql-output-perf).But it has below [features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#stream-data-from-blob-storage) for your references.

> Stream Analytics does not support adding content to an existing blob
>   file. Stream Analytics will view each file only once, and any changes
>   that occur in the file after the job has read the data are not
>   processed. Best practice is to upload all the data for a blob file at
>   once and then add additional newer events to a different, new blob
>   file.